# Ruby lambda syntax issue

Tags: ruby, lambda

I have some Ruby code

```
def a(x, y)
  puts x, y.call
end

a :a, -> do
  [1, 2, 3].map! do |j|
    j
  end
end
```

I'm almost sure that it's correct, editor highlights it as correct, but I have such exception:

```
SyntaxError: (irb):6: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end
  [1, 2, 3].map! do |j|
                   ^
(irb):9: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

Comment: It may be related to usage of `do` and `end` instead of `{}`, since the block applies to the last expression here, not to the `a` method call.  And it works with `{}` instead of `do` and `end`. But it also works with `do`/`end` and without inner block. So it may be a false trail.

Comment: Or add bracket like ... 

`a(:a, -> do ... end)`

Comment: Yes, It works, but I thought that `{..}` and `do..end` are equivalent

Comment: yes both will work, you need is to add `( )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm not totally mistaken, you need to wrap the method call in parentheses like this

```
def a(x, y)
  puts x, y.call
end

a(:a, -> do
  [1, 2, 3].map! do |j|
    j
  end
end)
```

Now there still is problem that you are passing two parameters to *puts* where only one is allowed, so you would need to concatenate the string with + or some other way.